# Java CM api for ClearCase throw exception

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Here is the full exception:

```
CRVAP0087E (conflict):  CCRC command 'Update' failed: 
Unable to get contents of directory "E:\ccweb_views\akash.sharma\akash.sharma_AR_TAS_Release1_int_2\rainwater\src\TAS\codegenerator\pom.xml": 
ClearCase object not found
Problems were encountered while retrieving view synchronization information and data.
```

It goes on with:

```
ClearCase CM Server: Error: 
Unable to access "\rainwater\src\TAS\codegenerator\pom.xml": Permission denied.

at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:538)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.Util.ccrcCmdStatusToWvcmException(Util.java:155)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.Util.runCommandAndCheckResults(Util.java:107)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.WebViewRefresh.run(WebViewRefresh.java:151)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.doRefresh(CcFileImpl.java:240)
    at Refresh_View.main(Refresh_View.java:65)
```

How would you troubleshoot that?

Answer (score 0):

If there is some kind of permission issue, you need to check:

- what user is actually executing the Java call?
- What is its <del>`PRIMARY_CLEARCASE_GROUP` (environment variable)</del>?
  (As you found out in your question "[Java CM api for ClearCase throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932433/how-to-check-user-group-in-clear-case-client-server/4932612#4932612)", `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` cannot be used with the [CCRC CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021929) or, I suspect, with the Java CM API)

You need to make sure that user has a main ClearCase group within the groups (primary or secondary) of the Vob '`rainwater`'

Answer (score -1):

If you are 100% sure the user is already in the correct group, fixprot might help.

Comment: There is no fix_prot.exe on a CCRC installation: a CCRC client has no view: all the snapshot 'web' views are on the CM CCRC server (where you could in theory make a `fix_prot` *there*)

Comment: What I meant to say is, on the server side, the CC admin could use fixprot to correct any bad protection. Obviously this cannot be done by a regular CC user with CCRC.