# How to check user group in ClearCase client server

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

With a full ClearCase installation, `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` is the usual way to set the main group for a user.

What about a CCRC installation through CLI (Java CM CLI or CCRC CLI)?
The GUI allows to set a primary group, but how would you set it through command lines?

Answer (score 2):

With CCRC, the [technote swg21423936](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21423936) mentions:

> The [ClearCase Remote Client Command Line Interface](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021929) does not support the ability to pass a specific client side ClearCase Group (such as `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`) or pass a defined set of user groups that should be used for the specific client logins (such as `CLEARCASE_GROUPS`).
>
> The CCRC GUI client does allow these preferences to be set.

The only workaround is to set a default primary group on the server side (the CM CCRC server)

> If the CM Server is a Windows server, an administrator can set the value of the `ccrcPrimaryGroup` mBean on the CM Server. This is a primary group name for all users who access that CM Server. Default value is "" (empty string or unset). Can be set to the empty string (to unset the override).
>
> Note: This is not available on UNIX or Linux CM Servers
>
> For information about setting mBean variables refer to the ClearCase Administrators documentation under the topic of [Setting available MBean attributes](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/cm_server/admin_console.htm).